# Can you protect social media iconography?

Tags: icon, copyright, legal

I frequently create mock-ups with free-use icon sets. I've begun to see many designers offer "Premium" commercial licenced sets of Social Media icons.

I'm wondering:

Is it even possible to make an IP (Intellectual Property) claim on branded logos redrawn in an icon set?

My guess is no... but I've never run into the issue before. I would imagine it would be difficult to claim the Facebook logo as your original work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are considered derivatives, and it is expressly frowned upon by the logo owner. Use policy of the logo clearly outline what you can and cannot do with their logo...

[image]
https://www.facebookbrand.com/guidelines?asset=2&media=1,2,3

especially if they are to be "associated" with the parent company (a new image on a site that links to the facebook page is a no no per their guidelines, unless it falls within the parameters they have stated)

Technically, you cannot claim "IP" to a redesign of a logo because trademark law covers the original from such a claim. You are copying their work, re-purposing it, and then claiming it as your own for sale... huge liability there.

You can certainly sell it, and make a little money on it if you wanted to, but it's not to say that it is legal, right, or acceptable. If you get caught, hefty fines could be imposed.

...

Your best bet is to go right to the source... here are a few examples to find out how THEY want you to handle their logos...

https://www.facebookbrand.com/dos-donts

https://about.twitter.com/press/twitter-brand-policy

http://www.google.com/permissions/using-the-logo.html

https://github.com/logos

http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance

http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/branding-guidelines